# Haskell app crashes: Segmentation fault/access violation in generated code

Tags: haskell, segmentation-fault, access-violation, ghc

Sadly, but this is a fact. My multi-threaded Haskell app crashes with this message. Obviously this bug is in a compiler implementation or code-generator, not in my code, due to Haskell in substance does not allow do something that may lead to such crashes. Where may I report such kind of bugs?

Comment: It's easy to crash a Haskell program, I'd grep my sources for functions with "unsafe" in their name (this naming convention is followed by most packages) and replace the occurrences with the safe variants (and see if this produces more meaningful errors, like "out of bounds") before assuming a GHC bug.

Comment: Also some interfaces are inherently unsafe.  For example, anything in `Foreign.Ptr` can cause segfaults due to coding errors, as can functions imported via the FFI.

Comment: Just to second that -- ghc bugs are a possibility but its far more common that one or another library is doing something tricky under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/

Here little instructions that will help you to make a proper report: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug